# JSON parsing and store data in SQLite

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am getting a JSON string (from MySQL) which has following data:
1. Restaurant name
2. Dishes of the associated restaurant. Each dish in turn has name, votes, likes, dislikes, reviews etc. Dishes can be around 50-100 per restaurant.

The JSON contains multiple restaurants i.e. a list of restaurants.

I want to know:
Should I first parse the JSON string and then store the data in the SQLite (for future fater retreival) but the number of dishes is high. For e.g. lets say I get 4 restaurants in the JSON string and each of them has around 50 dishes i.e. 4 x 50 = 200. This way I'll be storing 200 records at a point. Won't it hamper the performance of the application and database?

Please suggest how should I store the data of JSON string?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your JSON String as one/few records.

Restaurant column,JSON dishes column.

and then parse this data as you want.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your requirements. As you said the data comes with likes, dislikes and votes, which is likely to change fairly frequently. Therefore storing it in a DB will serve no purpose. My suggestion is you fetch the data every time someone opens the app and store it in a bean/class/arraylist. It might take some time for the app to start but will provide freash data to the user.

Comment: Actually main problem in coming in forming a sql query.